# Regex To Validate An Absolute Url

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to build a regex to validate the following  absolute url, here only the "/abc" and "/abc.exe" should be valid else all should be invalid.

Valid

- www.example.com/abc
- www.example.com/abc.exe

InValid

- www.example.com
- www.examplec.com/bbb
- www.examplec.com/bbb.exe
- all others other than above two.

Being new to regex I am trying this site - http://www.regexr.com/ to build one. Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following `regex` is probably what you want. You can make it more general to cover a wider range of possibilities:

`^www\.example\.com\/abc(\.exe)?$`

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/tF0wA8

For a more generic regex, you would probably need something like:

`^w{3}\.[^.]+\.(com|net|org|gov|edu)\/[^.]+(\.exe)?$`

Comment: Hey, thanks but i want only for absolute path i.e for "/abc" and "/abc.exe" can u pls help me with that too

Comment: @Yasser, In that case, the first regex works for you. See the demo.

Comment: @Yasser, No. Because `^` means start of string and `$` means end of string. This means that your regex would only match `'abc'` and `'abc.exe'`